# Page reload not showing message

Tags: magento2, ajaxaddtocart, error-message

Using **Codazon** theme developed **AjaxCartPro** Module

Problem - when a user put product qty more than **10000** no error is showing but just reloading the page

**we want to reload then show error message**

[app\code\Codazon\AjaxCartPro\Controller\Cart\Add.php](https://textuploader.com/15sr9)

[app\code\Codazon\AjaxCartPro\view\frontend\web\js\catalog-add-to-cart.js](https://textuploader.com/15srk)

Comment: @ShoaibMunir -  that's the demo link which it supposed to be :)

Comment: Yes @Danes It's showing error message when i put 1000 qty as Shoaib said. Also in my instance as well.

Comment: @Vivek ---- just want to reload then show error message... any suggestion? please have look at above code linked...

Answer (score 0):

If you are not getting error message on product page, then you need to do some custom coding in your product main .phtml file

```
<script>
require([
    'jquery'
], function($){
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        //Display error if found after jquery
        var messages = $.cookieStorage.get('mage-messages');
        if (!_.isEmpty(messages)) {
            customerData.set('messages', {messages: messages});
            $.cookieStorage.set('mage-messages', '');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

This is the part when system check if message set on cookie and will will appear

If above code not work for you then you need to add this code in `window load` instead of `document ready`

Comment: have you checked the files Add.php and catalog-add-to-cart.js. with an above success message is showing but not the error message it just reload the page

Comment: Add.php add splash message and catalog-add-to-cart.js used for ajax add to cart. Now that your page is reload, catalog-add-to-cart.js would not execute code to show message

Comment: However, this is magento default behavior that it shows splash message on page load, I don't know why you website is not showing error message. Please try my code, see if it work for you